# Select IN with an array with duplicate value on it

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a request where I select from an array of value using the `IN`, but inside this array, if I have the same value twice, I'd like the request to return the result twice.

To clarify, here is an example:

```
select id_exo, count(id_exo) FROM BLOC WHERE id_seance IN (10,10) group by id_exo
```

So inside the `IN`, I put 2 times the value 10.

Here is the result:

| id_exo | count(id_exo) |
| --- | --- |
| 60 | 1 |
| 82 | 1 |

But in count, I'd like to have the number 2 since I have put twice 10 inside my `IN`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You would need to use a join instead of `IN`.

Comment: ok thanks for answering but how to pass an array using a join ?

Comment: I didn't answer, I posted a comment that pointed in the direction of the solution. I don't use MySQL, so I don't know its ins and outs. Though technically, your question as asked doesn't involve arrays. You have an `IN` with a list of literal values, in SQL terms that is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id_exo, COUNT(id_exo) 
FROM bloc 
JOIN (SELECT 10 id_seance 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 10) val USING (id_seance)
GROUP BY id_exo
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to MySQL 8.0 you can join with a sub select:

```
select * from BLOC as b
inner join (
  select 1 as 'id', 10 as 'value' 
  union 
  select 2,10 
  union 
  select 3,10) as myValues on myValues.value = b.id_seance
```

You need the id column as the UNION statement removes duplicate rows

If you are lucky enough to have MySQL 8.0 look at the VALUES statement
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Here you should instead be able to join with something like

```
VALUES ROW(10), ROW(10), ROW(10)
```